# compareTo with generic linkedList

Tags: java, generics, comparable, compareto, cannot-find-symbol

I am new to java and i have encountered a problem while making a generic class with comparable interface. In the sortedInsert method of LinkedList class it gives error on head.value.compareTo(new_node.value), i am making an object of Linkedlist class in main so ,   according to my understanding head.value should give me an employee object for which i am calling compareTo . but still it gives me this error . is there anything i understood incorrectly ? or making a mistake in this code .

**cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method compareTo(T)**

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
private int empID;
private String name;
private int salary;
private boolean manager;
private int subordinates;

public Employee()
{
    empID = 0;
    name = "";
    salary = 0;
    manager = false;
    subordinates = 0;
}



public Employee(int id , String name , int salary , boolean manager , int sub)
{
    empID = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.manager = manager;
    subordinates = sub;
}

public int  GetID()
{
    return this.empID;
}


public String GetName()
{
    return this.name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee other)
{
    if (this.empID < other.empID)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (this.empID > other.empID)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


public class LinkedList<T>
   {
    private int count;
    private Node<T> head;



    private class Node<T>
    {
        public T value;
        public Node<T> next;


        public Node(T data)
        {
            this.value = data;
            this.next = null;
        }


    }


    LinkedList()
    {
        count = 0;
        head = null;
    }



    void sortedInsert(T data)
    {

        Node<T> current;
Node<T> new_node = new Node<T>(data);

         /* Special case for head node
           head.value >= newNode*/

        if (head == null || (head.value.compareTo(new_node.value) == 1 || head.value.compareTo(new_node.value) == 0))
        {
            new_node.next = head;
            head = new_node;
        }
        else {


            current = head;

            while (current.next != null && (current.next.value.compareTo(new_node.value) == -1))
                current = current.next;

            new_node.next = current.next;
            current.next = new_node;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to switch to this:

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Comment: -1 the code does indeed work but you did not give any explanations of as why it works. OP is new to java without learning the reason OP would likely make the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The `head.value` variable is not necessarily something that implements Comparable interface.  You need to either define your `LinkedList<T>` such that it must implement `Comparable` (see @algrid's answer) or cast it when using the `compareTo` method.